# How to show a matter constraint without the debug view in phaser 3?

Tags: game-physics, phaser-framework, matter.js

I am creating a game in Phaser 3 using the Matter physics framework. I have a sprite that "shoots" a constraint that attaches to objects, which works fine. My problem is however, the only way this constraint can be shown is when `debug` is set to `true`. I want to be able to view the constraint when debug is off, but I am not sure of the best way to do this.

The constraint is basically a rope that the player swings on in the game, and I'd like to be able to draw it as a line.

I have tried drawing a line, but couldn't seem to get the `x` and `y` coordinates right for the origin. I have also tried turning my sprite and tiles' debug view off so that I could keep debug on, and only show the constraint, but I couldn't get the tile's debug view to turn off, nor would this be very practical.

Code where the constraint is added:

```
this.rope = this.matter.add.constraint(this.player, this.web, distance, 0.1, {pointA: {x: 27.5, y: 5}});
```

Comment: I haven't been able to figure it out yet. Can you share the link from where your implementation of the rope?

Comment: @ManuelAbascal https://www.emanueleferonato.com/2019/03/08/fling-unity-game-built-in-html5-with-phaser-and-matter-js-updated-with-the-latest-constraints-tweaks-fly-through-the-screen-with-your-ninja-rope/. I tried looking here https://phaser.discourse.group/t/creating-rope-physics-using-matterjs-within-phaser/1140/5 for inspiration, and commented, but the author has yet to reply

Comment: Have you tried to an image to the rope?

Comment: There’s an image in the images folder in the repository where i had one, but I couldn’t seem to get it to work. Placing an image or a line is the easy part, having it behave like the rope is the hard part

Comment: I don't think we can see the constraint with debug set to `false`. You might have to create sprite & set its `position.x` to the same length of the constraints in order to recreate this functionality.

Comment: You’re right, I even asked the creator of Phaser on discord and he said you cant. You’re right also that we could do that, but how would we set it so that it changes length just like the constraint?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202961/discussion-between-manuel-abascal-and-robert-smith).

Comment: @ManuelAbascal I have made good progress on the line1

Answer (score 2):

I went through the very same struggle in attempt to reproduce the debug view without the debug flag toggled on, by creating visible game objects and matching their positions to that of corresponding Matter constraint bodies.

Some day it occurred to me why should it be so laborious if I could leverage some of the internal rendering functions that are exactly designed for the debug view.

Then I went diving deep into the documentation with the keywords such as debug/render/draw etc., and picked a clue.

> Phaser.Physics.Matter.World: An instance of the Matter World class.
> This class is responsible for the updating of the Matter Physics
> world, **as well as handling debug drawing functions**.
> https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Physics.Matter.World.html

And as I inspect into this class, I've found

> **renderConstraint** renders a single Matter Constraint, such as a Pin or a Spring, to the given Phaser Graphics Game Object.
>
> This method is used internally by the Matter Debug Renderer, but is also exposed publicly **should you wish to render a Constraint to your own Graphics instance**.

```
renderConstraint(constraint, graphics, lineColor, lineOpacity, lineThickness, pinSize, anchorColor, anchorSize)
```

https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Physics.Matter.World.html#renderConstraint__anchor

, which is exactly what we need!

**So, here is the solution: call this function in update(). And don't forget to add a graphics object on which the view is rendered.**

```
renderDebug() {
  if (!this.graphics) {
    this.graphics = this.add.graphics();
  }

  this.graphics.clear();

  this.matter.world.renderConstraint(this.rope, this.graphics, color, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1);
}
```

What's more, there are a bunch of rendering functions design for different type of matter bodies such as *renderBodyAxes, renderBodyBounds, renderCollisions*...Basically you can find all these functions corresponding to the debug view option.

Digging into the documentation could be like treasure hunt, which I love but also hate about.